# Como hago en windows con un botón que me borre carácter por carácter

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy desarrollando una calculadora en windows forms ya la termine pero me falta configurar un botón y es que conocemos como CE.
El requisito es que este botón me borre cierto carácter digamos yo quiero sumar 
( 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 ) pero se me fue el numero que no era ejemplo ( 2 + 2 + 2 + 5 ) como hago que este botón me borre solo el ( 5 ) sin limpiar toda la caja de texto ya que tendría que hacer de nuevo toda la operación. 
Gracias a quien logre ayudarme solo me falta esto nada mas.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías mostrar el código para saber en que parte estás. Pero así como lo dices creo que podrías usar el Substring en un evento clic del botón CE.
Si en tu TextBox tienes "2+2+2+5" entonces deberías hacer Algo así:

```
if(TxtFiltrado.Text.Length > 2)
   string resultado = TxtFiltrado.Text.Substring(0, TxtFiltrado.Text.Length - 2);
```

dando como resultado ="2+2+2" ya que elimina los dos últimos dígitos.
Espero haberte ayudado.